# Can Squid3 access PHP Helpers

Tags: ubuntu, php, proxy, squid, access-control-list

Can Squid3 use PHP helper programs other than for ACL and redirect?

I need Squid to use a PHP program (with mysql access) to set the parent proxy that should be used for a particular connection, so the program should be able to set values for `cache_peer` etc for that connection.

*I may have the entire approach wrong, please correct me if that's so*

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve this way?